# Only login and logout flow works in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, blazor

I followed the official guide from Microsoft to setup [ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which worked perfectly, login opens a new window that asks for credential and logout refresh the page and logs me out. I checked the code and it seems that in order to do login or logout you just need to set the action in

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

and based on the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-app-routes) the available routes are

```
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             Route              |                                  Purpose                                   |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| authentication/login           | Triggers a sign-in operation.                                              |
| authentication/login-callback  | Handles the result of any sign-in operation.                               |
| authentication/login-failed    | Displays error messages when the sign-in operation fails for some reason.  |
| authentication/logout          | Triggers a sign-out operation.                                             |
| authentication/logout-callback | Handles the result of a sign-out operation.                                |
| authentication/logout-failed   | Displays error messages when the sign-out operation fails for some reason. |
| authentication/logged-out      | Indicates that the user has successfully logout.                           |
| authentication/profile         | Triggers an operation to edit the user profile.                            |
| authentication/register        | Triggers an operation to register a new user.                              |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I tried to use actions **profile** and **register**.

- **profile** shows me `Editing the profile is not supported.` message
- **register** redirects me back to homepage with a `?returnUrl=%2Fauthentication%2Flogin` query parameter

I want to do both register and update profile.

Comment: have you created user flow for ProfileEdit? The register is working as expected, you can register a user from the login page(for this you need signuporsignin userflow).

Comment: @Manish yes I did create the user flow for ProfileEdit, but I didn't add the name anywhere in my code, don't know where I should add it. Yes I can register from login flow but I wanted to show the register page without the as login intermediate

Comment: Youll need to dynamically change the authority param in the `wwwroot/appsettings.json` file to include the Policy ID of the respective User Flow you are trying to invoke when the user makes the action in the App

Comment: @JasSuri I don't really understand this, can you show me an example?

Comment: Did you modify the value of `Authority` in `appsettings.json` file as Jas Suri suggested? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authentication-service-support.

Comment: Yes I did, authority points to the login/register flow

Comment: @Almis did you find out how to get this to work? Calling "authentication/register" from my blazor webassembly app gives me the same "not supported" message as you.

Comment: @sharpc No, I gave up on it

Comment: @Almis, Did you find any way to call the signup and profile edit userflows from the Blazor app?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar no I gave up on it, don't remember anything